# Many to many PATCH not immediately showing up in response Django REST Framework 2.4.3

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

It seems that performing a `PATCH` on an endpoint with a `many-to-many` relation updates the object but doesn't return back the updated data until the next response vs returning it back in the `PATCH` response.

**Example with original object:**

```
{
    "id": 35, 
    "interests": [
        1, 
        2
    ], 
    "personal_statement": "Hello World", 
    "photo": "", 
    "resume": "", 
    "user": 2
}
```

**PATCH request setting `interests=[1,2,3,4,5]` ... Example response:**

```
{
    "id": 35, 
    "interests": [
        1, 
        2
    ], 
    "personal_statement": "Hello World", 
    "photo": "", 
    "resume": "", 
    "user": 2
}
```

**Example of next `GET` Response:**

```
{
    "id": 35, 
    "interests": [
        1, 
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5
    ], 
    "personal_statement": "Hello World", 
    "photo": "", 
    "resume": "", 
    "user": 2
}
```

This is using Django v1.7.4 and Django REST Framework v2.4.3

My first assumption is that since it's a many to many relation it is saving the parent object first and returning back that data before saving the many to many relation data, but I'm not entirely sure. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

## EDIT

The issue is actually an open issue on Django REST Framework with some possible solutions. It was being caused by `prefetch_related` in my ViewSet queryset:
https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1556
https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/2442

Answer (score 0):

According to REST API patterns,  `PATCH` request performs a partial update, so `Django-Rest-Framework` just returns updated data.

May be you want to override `PATCH view` to return complete serializer data  or change your `PATCH` request to `PUT` one.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same while adding prefetch_related to a many to many field I had. I solved it by simply adding a custom update to my serializer:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    super(SimpleClientModelResource, self).update(instance, validated_data)
    return self.Meta.model.objects.get(id=instance.id)
```